# How to align an item at the end of a card, vertically centred (Using bootstrap 4)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a long bootstrap card with two rows of information, a title and description. I would then like a button, aligned to the right of this card, centrally. My current html is as follows for the button:

```
<div class="card card-body">
  <h4>I'm a Card</h4>
  <p>The button should be central, at the end of this card.</p>
  <input type="button"
        class="btn btn-outline-primary align-self-end"
        value=".align-self-end">
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/ZEbyNXe

As you can see, the button is placed at the bottom of the card causing its height to increase. How can I ensure it is always at the end, at the centre of the card, and does not increase the height of said card? Thanks.

Comment: The message in `<p>` already tell you the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean, could you possibly change the codepen to show me what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: "My card-body is display:flex, flex-direction:column". Just extract the setting from it.

Comment: I have tried changing flex-direction to row but it doesn't seem to change anything?

Comment: I don't see any CSS settings on your codepen page.

Comment: This is using bootstrap. You have to override or add new CSS.

Comment: Hint: Did you try change the class named `align-self-end` to some else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex-direction: row` to the card, add a container for the content, and on the button change `align-self-end` to `align-self-center`.

```css
.mycard {
  flex-direction: row!important;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card card-body mycard">
        <div>
          <h4>I'm a Card</h4>
          <p>
            The button should be central, at the end of this card.
          </p>
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary align-self-center" value="Button">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was looking for- would it be possible to change padding/margin of the button afterwards etc?

Comment: There's no need to change `flex-direction` to `row`.

Comment: Actually, this is nearly there- the only problem is that when you go into full page, it is not staying to the right hand side as the width of the card increases?

Comment: Added `justify-content: space-between;` that solves this